# Frameset Alternative link not working

Tags: frameset

I am looking for an alternative solution to HTML Framesets and from what I have read so far, I can use DIVs with CSS to create column contents. Basically, I want my images in one column on the left and when clicked should call details.php (tagged as id=details) in the column on the right.

I have started off with the following; unfortunately, clicking links in the left column is not calling anything in the right column:

```
<div class="col1">
            <a href="details.php?PersonID=<?php echo $PersonID; ?>" target=details> <?php echo $row['FamilyName']; ?> <?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?> </a>
        </div>


    <div class="col2" id="details">
        <?php   $file = file_get_contents('./details.php', true); ?> 
    </div>
```

I will appreciate any advise to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine HTML & CSS with jQuery or any javascript libraries to load the content (details.php) asynchronously using AJAX.

`$('a').on('click', function(e) { 
    var contentUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#details').load(contentUrl, function() {
      console.log('the content has been loaded is appended into the div');
    });
});`

For more reference you can go to [jQuery API - load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).